# There's a way to filter changes commit on Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, filter, commit

I'd like to know if exists some way (Jenkins plug-in) to filter commits that you doesn't want to see, for example exclude someone who belongs to other team.

Thank you very much,

Regards

Comment: Keep them in a different branch if you don't want their pull requests to be included. :P

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming you are using polling to determine if Jenkins should run a build*

It's possible to do this using the git-plugin.

Under `Source Code Management` > `Additional Behaviours` you will have options for:

- Polling ignores commits from certain users
- Polling ignores commits in certain paths
- Polling ignores commits with certain messages

**EDIT**

For subversion, the [Subversion Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin) might have what you want.

Under `Source Code Management` > `Advanced` you can find the following options:

- Excluded Regions
- Included Regions
- Excluded Users
- Excluded Commit Messages

Comment: I'm really sorry, i'm using SVN, there are some other ways?